# How to cleanly deal with warning about the repository `hirsute InRelease` which doesn't have the component `bionic-security`?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

So under Ubuntu 21.04 I somehow end up with a file specifying an apt source that trigger a warning saying that the repository `hirsute InRelease` doesn't have the component `bionic-security`.

I was wondering if I could safely remove some part of the corresponding line, the whole line, or event the whole `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_security_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-hirsute.list` file, without introduce some security vulnerabilities on the system. Or otherwise, what would be the correct safe way to fix this warning?

An other question that it rises for me is, is bionic some specific repository of Ubuntu which is supposed to be cross version?

Bellow is a list of command with their output to give more contextual information.

```
# LANG=C lsb_release -a 

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute


# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_security_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-hirsute.list`

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute bionic-security main

LANG=C sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                                     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                             
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                         
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                                                                                                
Hit:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Ign:7 https://dl.packager.io/srv/deb/opf/openproject/stable/11/ubuntu 20.04 InRelease                                                                          
Get:8 https://dl.packager.io/srv/deb/opf/openproject/stable/11/ubuntu 20.04 Release
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Fetched 1221 B in 1s (1420 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic-security/source/Sources' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic-security' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

## Similar questions explored

- [How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121069/how-to-resolve-skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)
- [Getting tons of warnings "skipped acquire" when doing apt update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039187/getting-tons-of-warnings-skipped-acquire-when-doing-apt-update)
- [Skipping errors with sudo apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252516/skipping-errors-with-sudo-apt-get-update)
- [Getting apt warnings when updating Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145986/getting-apt-warnings-when-updating-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) . The 21.04 is hirsute, it should contain only hirsute, hirsute-updates, hirsute-security, maybe hirsute-backports. The bionic-updates for hirsute is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: Do you download deb-src *source* packages? They are different than the usual *binary* packages. Source packages are used only if you compile your own binaries. If you DO use source packages, easily fix the typo in the line: Replace `hirsute bionic-security` with `hirsute-security`. If you DON'T use source packages, simply comment out or delete that unused line.

Comment: It does the job. Thanks @user535733 :) Please put it as answer so I can validate it.

Comment: Which does the job? Fixing the typo? Or commenting out Source Packages? You are welcome to answer your own question, too. The process you used may help others.

Comment: Yep, sorry for my lake of explication. I went with "Replace hirsute bionic-security with hirsute-security". Thanks